# ListView inside another ListView

Tags: android, json, listview, android-listview, custom-lists

i have a custom list View that populates my screen with posts. some of the posts have comments which is why I need the other list View so that the comments can be displayed with the post. I'm using volley and have made a post class which has getter and setter methods for the different attributes. I'm using a custom list View adapter to display the post details but I don't understand how to display the comments as well. Could someone please help me by explaining the best way to achieve this?

this is an example of the JSON that will be used:

```
{ 
  id: "10",
  author_id: "1",
  name: "John",
  picture: "uploads/image.jpg",
  text: "hello this is my first post:)"
  comments: [
      {
            comment: "Hello",
            comment_id: "1",
            comment_author_id: "2",
            post_id: "10"
      },
      {
            comment: "Hi",
            comment_id: "2",
            comment_author_id: "1",
            post_id: "10"
      },
   ]
},
{ 
  id: "11",
  author_id: "3",
  name: "Jane",
  picture: "uploads/image_2.jpg",
  text: "hello World ! "
  comments: []
},
```

I would like it to look like the image below, so comments are displayed with the post:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfzNw.jpg

Any help would be great :)

Comment: Called [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can't put listview in listview. You should add comments like layouts.

```
LinearLayout commentsLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.commentsLayout);
View comment = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.comment);
commentsLayout.addView(comment);
```

Comment: How would i show multiple comments under a post if i use linearlayout

Answer (score 0):

you should make a Custom Adapter for the list view ,meaning you set a layout for each row ,and then you parse the json ..I think this link will help you : https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView